# Excel formulas not working correctly in all cells

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2013

The same formula does not work in some cells. (same problem in other sheets) The cells seem to be random. I have Auto Calculate on and have been careful to have all cells formatted the same, etc. (tried several options). The formula is: =IF(U110<>$X$1,"ERROR IN TIMING",""). What is wrong?..Working in Excel 2013.Some cells will calculate as ERROR IN TIMING, while others will remain blank, as they should. I have even tried the Array brackets.

Comment: Post a data sample. What is in U110 and X1? Numbers? Text? Numbers stored as text are not the same as numbers stored as numbers. Post a file with the problem on a file sharing service, then paste a link here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry, not sure how to post a file yet.I will try and figure that out if needed.  As an example, the formula is in T110 formatted as General, U110 is formatted as Time (h:mm) as is X1. U110 has a formulla (=B110+Y110), X1 has a reference entry of 9:15 as U110 normally would calculate to. B110 + Y110 are also formatted as h:mm.

Comment: Please read. Post a file with the problem **on a file sharing service**, then paste a link here. – You can't post a file here.

Answer (score 0):

If the cells are showing time values, it is possible that a cell formatted with h:mm is showing only the time portion, but the underlying value is much bigger.

For example: 12 noon is the number 0.5. Formatted as h:mm it will show as 12:00 am. If you add 24 hours to that time, the underlying number is 1.5, but the cell formatted with h:mm will still only show 12:00 am.

Even though the two cells show the same times, they do not have the same value and a comparison of the two cells will show they are not the same. Refer to cells B1 and B2 in the screenshot. The formula in D1 returns FALSE, because the two cells don't have the same value.

[image]

Check the underlying values of the cells.

Comment: Good reply, so I tried changing all the time cells to hh:mm;ss;AM. They now all read AM, however some of the formulas are stiil incorrect. No change.

Comment: Try formatting without AM / PM. Try `[hh]:mm:ss` which will show hours greater than 24. Or format the values as General, then you can see the actual underlying value.  If that does not help, post a file that shows the problem.